# Align and space 3 images in android, taking full width

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 3 images and I would like to achieve to have something like my  [image: screenshot]

It is supposed to take the full width of the screen, a height of 100dp (or whatever I will choose).

The images I have are square and big. I want them to have a height of 100dp, keep their aspect ratio (square) and be spaced equally

What I get with this code is 3 images that take 1/3 of the width, not squared with no space in between

I have tried various things (playing with `scaleType`, ...) but I am stuck (apart from setting the width to 100dp manually for each of them, which I conceptually don't like)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/img1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/img2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/img3"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it with code:

```
int resx = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
int spaceBetweenPics = (resx - 300) / 2; // Two spaces taking resolution - 3 images size
Bitmap [] pics = New Bitmap[3];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)  {
    pics[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img1 + i); 
    // With their names, they are contiguous in the drawables index
    pics[i] = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(pics[i], 100, 100, false);
}
```

In your onDraw method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    canvas.drawBitmap(pics[i], (100 * i + spaceBetweenPics * i), 0, null);
```